# Javascript Canvas - Check if clicking on rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas with a grid, and if the user clicks on a rectangle, it should be filled with a color. What I'm having trouble doing is checking if the user is clicking on a rectangle already colored, so the program can either remove it or change its color.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/JQd4j/2/

```
var build_canvas = document.getElementById("builder-canvas");
var build_context = build_canvas.getContext("2d");
var builder = function () {

    var x;
    for (x = 0.5; x <= 800; x += 15) {
        build_context.moveTo(x, 0);
        build_context.lineTo(x, 390);
    }

    var y;
    for (y = 0.5; y < 400; y += 10) {
        build_context.moveTo(0, y);
        build_context.lineTo(796, y);
    }

    build_context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    build_context.stroke();
};
builder();

build_context.fillStyle = 'red';
build_canvas.onclick = function (e) {
    var rect = build_canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    x = Math.floor((x / 15)) * 15;
    y = Math.floor((y / 10)) * 10;

    build_context.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, 14, 9);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array which corresponds to the grid. When clicked simply set the array's value to something else than what it is initially.

Initialize an array with number of columns x number of rows:

```
var cols = 27;
var rows = 40;
var clicked = new Uint8Array(cols * rows);  // initialized with 0
```

Then simply calculate the index of the cell in that array and check for a value, for example 1:

```
build_canvas.onclick = function (e) {

    var rect = build_canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top,
        cellX = (x / 15)|0,           // get hor. cell position
        cellY = (y / 10)|0,           // get ver. cell position
        index = cols * cellY + cellX; // get array index

    if (clicked[index] === 1) {       // clicked ? (===1)
        alert('clicked already');     // do some action
        return;
    }

    clicked[index] = 1;               // is clicked now...

    x = cellX * 15;                   // get pixel position
    y = cellY * 10;

    build_context.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, 14, 9);
}
```

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/JQd4j/4/)**

The index of a 1-dimensional array representing a 2D array is always calculated `width x y position + x position`.

Comment: You again, @Epistemex. Thank you! You are the best. I'm having a little trouble working with canvas, since I started learning about it today. I'm gonna now try to change the code to switch colors when some actions are performed. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Marcos no problem, just glad to help :) Feel free to throw us more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, by checking the color of where you are trying to paint:

```
    var p = build_context.getImageData(x+1, y+1, 1, 1).data; 
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
    if(hex=='#000000'){
        build_context.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, 14, 9);
    }else{
        //do something
    }


function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}
```